# How can I configure NestJS to continue after it has encountered an exception?

Tags: exception, configuration, nestjs, internal-server-error

I'm using NestJS 10.  I start my server locally using

```
npm run start:dev
```

which is defined in my package.json as

```
"start:dev": "nest start --watch",
```

Having an issue where if a controller method throws an exception, the server is unable to respond to any other request.  For example, I have this controller method ...

```
@Controller(ORDERS_CONTEXT_PATH)
export class OrdersController {
  constructor(private readonly ordersService: OrdersService) {}

  @UseGuards(OptionalAccessTokenGuard)
  @Post('paymentIntent')
  createPaymentIntent(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Body() createOrderItemDtos: CreateOrderItemDto[],
  ): Promise<PaymentIntent> {
    const userId = req.user ? req.user['sub'] : null;
    return this.ordersService.createPaymentIntent(userId, createOrderItemDtos);
  }
```

If the underlying service throws an exception, the NestJS console reports it ...

```
/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/src/orders/orders.service.ts:43
      createOrderDto.orderItems.map(async (orderItemDto) => {
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')
    at /Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/src/orders/orders.service.ts:47:18
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OrdersService.create (/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/src/orders/orders.service.ts:43:33)
    at runOriginal (/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/node_modules/typeorm-transactional/src/transactions/wrap-in-transaction.ts:53:34)
    at OrdersService.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/node_modules/typeorm-transactional/src/transactions/wrap-in-transaction.ts:117:20)
    at step (/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/node_modules/typeorm-transactional/dist/transactions/wrap-in-transaction.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/node_modules/typeorm-transactional/dist/transactions/wrap-in-transaction.js:14:53)
    at /Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/node_modules/typeorm-transactional/dist/transactions/wrap-in-transaction.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myproject/node_modules/typeorm-transactional/dist/transactions/wrap-in-transaction.js:4:12)
```

but now whenever I make other requests (even to different controllers), I repeatedly get

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

back from the server.  Is there a general way I configure my server to return a 500 if there is an underlying problem and allow it to continue to handle client requests?

Comment: A simple 500 error shouldn't be crashing the server. Do you have any custom guards in use or any other exceptions in the console?

Comment: surround the request handler in a try/catch block.

Comment: @WaisKamal, taht is a good patch solution, but I don't want to have to do that for every controller method across my application.  There shoudl be a simpler way to configure this.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, There is that guard there, "@UseGuards(OptionalAccessTokenGuard)", but even if I take that out, I observe the same behavior (the server process crashing, forcing me to restart it)

Comment: Usually a crash like that would mean that there's an exception happening outside of the lifecycle of the request

Comment: Would that kind of thing be detected in a stack trace?  I included the entirety of what I had in the question, but maybe there's a way I can set some kind of logging setting to determine if something is happening outside of the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in exception occurs during the processing of a request, the server may go into a failed state, making subsequent requests fail as well.

One solution to this issue is to add a **global exception filter** to your NestJS application. This filter will catch any unhandled exceptions and respond with an appropriate error status code, allowing the server to continue processing other requests. You can create a global exception filter by implementing the ExceptionFilter interface.

**Example** :

```
// create a file, e.g., global-exception.filter.ts

import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();

    const status =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
      message: 'Internal Server Error', // You can customize this message
    });
  }
}
```

Then, you need to apply this filter globally in your main application file (e.g., main.ts):

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { GlobalExceptionFilter } from './path/to/global-exception.filter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Apply the global exception filter
  app.useGlobalFilters(new GlobalExceptionFilter());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```